# How do I configure the IMediator (MassTransit) passed into a controller, using Autofac?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac, masstransit

I have the following .Net controller (highly simplified) that does something like this:

```
public class FooController{
    private MassTransit.Mediator.IMediator mediator;
        
    public FooController(MassTransit.Mediator.IMediator mediator)       
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;       
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task CreateFooJob(FooJobRequest myRequest){
        var client = mediator.CreateRequestClient<GoCreateJobRequest>();
        var response = await mediator.GetResponse<GoCreateJobResponse>(new GoCreateJobRequest(myRequest));
        return; 
    }
    public class GoCreateJobConsumer : IConsumer<GoCreateJobRequest>{
        //some work...
        await context.ResponseAsync<GoCreateJobResponse>(new GoCreateJobResponse());
    }
     
}
```

I am struggling with initialising the IMediator object using Autofac. The MassTransit documentation seems to think that something like this:

```
builder.AddMediator(c =>
{
    c.AddConsumer<GoCreateJobConsumer>();

});
```

Should work, but it does not - it does not connect the IMediator to a mediator object (which, makes sense since Autofac does not have anything registered for that). Instead, my WebApiConfig code looks like this (idea taken from the "Configuration" section of [this page of documntation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
build.Register(m => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateMediator(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Consumer<GoCreateJobConsumer>();
    })
);
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

This was actually working fairly nicely - when I debugged through my controller, I was able to step into the request. However, upon returning the response it failed and said "loopback://localhost/response => The message was not consumed".

I feel like I have scoured the internet and SO to get the answer to how to configure this thing, and I can't figure it out. Is there something I'm missing?? I feel like I'm missing something related to the Factory or Bus idea in the mediator configuration. Is there another way I should be approaching writing the controller that still gives me some D.I. but makes these configuration stuff work?? Thank you

Comment: According to the available [source code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.AutofacIntegration/AutofacRegistrationExtensions.cs#L44), `builder.AddMediator(...`  is a valid extension and should work. What do you mean that it does not work in your post.

Comment: @Nkosi By that I mean, when I build/run the solution and attempt to hit that HttpPost endpoint, an exception is thrown because IMediator is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

According to the available [source code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.AutofacIntegration/AutofacRegistrationExtensions.cs#L44), `builder.AddMediator(...`  is a valid extension and should work.

Simplified example

```
//...

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//add controllers
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

//setup mass transit
builder.AddMassTransit(x => {
    //...omitted for brevity
});

//configure mediator
builder.AddMediator(c => {
    c.AddConsumer<GoCreateJobConsumer>();    
});

var container = builder.Build();

config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! @Nkosi was correct that the `builder.AddMediator` function should be used to initialize it. However, the syntax is a bit off. Looking at the linked documentation, the `AddMediator` function returns a modified builder object. I'm not 100% sure why this worked, but returning the builder object and reassigning it to itself solved my problem. My code ends up looking like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder = builder.AddMediator(c => {
    c.AddConsumer<GoCreateJobConsumer>();    
});
```

Thank you Nkosi!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: What happens if you try chaining the calls ie (builder.A().B().C())